# Running different versions of postgresql side by side

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I have postgresql 9.3 installed.
I would like to have also postgres 9.6.1 installed.

Each application is using a different DB. Most of the times I don't run both applications, so I don't need them to run concurrently.

I downloaded the installer recommended by [postgres](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/pgdownload.do#linux), and installed 9.6.1, but then it seems that 9.3 is not able to start anymore. I'm getting an error trying to run `sudo service postgres start`:

> - Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
> - The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output.

The log file is empty (not sure that's the interesting one) - /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log

Any idea how to be able to run both instances?

Comment: `locate bin/pg_ctl` ?..

Comment: @VaoTsun /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl

Comment: try `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl start`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the postgresql.conf config file.

If you want to run both instances at the same time then they will need to be run on different ports otherwise they will conflict. The default is 5432, change this for one of the DB's.

Then make sure that the data directory, log file are unique for each instance.

Comment: It's not only the DB. For example when running this command I'm getting an error:

Comment: can you provide example of what you are doing  ?

Comment: One use case would be testing upgrade DB from older version to new one